# Unable to select image from Android gallery from another native app

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

Need to select an image from gallery through another native app but not able to select the image.

> Click on Add Image (on a Native App) -> From Library -> All Images -> Select the actual image

**Working Part of the Code:** Click on Add Image (on a Native App) -> From Library -> All Images

```
//Click Add Photo icon in the app to select an image from gallery

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(iconAddPhoto));
        iconAddPhoto.click();   

//Select from Library option when Take Photo/Choose from Library Option is shown
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(lnkChooseFromLibrary));
        lnkChooseFromLibrary.click();

//Select All Pictures folder when All Pictures and Whatsapp Image folders are displayed
        List<MobileElement> galleryElements = 
driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ImageView"));
        galleryElements.get(0).click();
```

**Not Working Part of the Code:** Selecting the actual Image from All Pictures Folder

```
//Tried the below combinations one at a time to select the actual image but the element is not getting detected

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'com.ebay.kijiji.ca:id/grid_item_image')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'com.ebay.kijiji.ca:id/grid_item_image')]")).get(0).click();

AndroidElement abc = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//android.widget.ImageButton[@bounds='[4,210][238,410]']"));
        abc.click();

List<MobileElement> galleryElements1 = driver.findElements(By.id("com.ebay.kijiji.ca:id/image_library_grid"));
        galleryElements1.get(0).click();

ArrayList<MobileElement> listImage=(ArrayList<MobileElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("com.ebay.kijiji.ca:id/image_library_grid"));
        System.out.println(listImage.size());
        listImage.get(5).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying the clicking on photo which is displayed in Grid.

Initially try to have fewer photos in the grid of the album since appium selects the element from the bottom of the grid.

```
    public void selectPhotos(int numberOfPhotos){

            //Find the grid element
            WebElement gridAlbum= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the full grid of album"));

            //Add the rows of element to the list
            List<WebElement> gridRows=gridAlbum.findElements(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the row element");

           //find the number of rows
            System.out.println("Number of Rows"+gridRows.size());

            for(WebElement row:gridRows) {

                List<WebElement> cells=row.findElements(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element");

                for(WebElement cell:cells) {

                    if(count>0) {
                    cell.click();
                    count--;
                    }
                    else
                      break;

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I used the above code but still I am getting no such element exception for grid element itself though the app has an id name and class name for grid element. Class Name - android.widget.GridView / id - om.ebay.kijiji.ca:id/image_library_grid